# Paragon Points not available for new season character

Tags: diablo-iii

I am new to Diablo III and reached paragon level 50 last night. I decided I would create a seasonal character. After reading a bit online I see that paragon points are account-wide. Someone who just joined my game is a level 1 with paragon level 250, whereas I'm still showing up as a level 1 with no paragon points.

How do I use my paragon points at level 1 on a new character?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, you don't. Paragon points are account wide per character "type". The Four types being:

- Non-Seasonal Softcore
- Non-Seasonal Hardcore (Permadeath)
- Seasonal Softcore
- Seasonal Hardcore (Permadeath)

If you are paragon level 50 in a Non-Seasonal type they do not carry over to a Seasonal Hero. You start a season 100% from scratch. When any character reaches level 70 you will start to earn Paragon experience again. Those paragon levels will be available to all of your seasonal character though.  At the end of the season all paragon experience earned will transfer over to their respective non-seasonal type as well.

For example you can have

Non-Seasonal Softcore - Paragon Level 50

- Level 70 Monk
- Level 50 Witch Doctor

Non-Seasonal Hardcore - Paragon Level 10

- Level 70 Barbarian

Seasonal Softcore - No Paragon Levels

- Level 40 Crusader

Seasonal Hardcore - Paragon Level 30

- Level 70 Monk

At the end of the Season your Seasonal character will become Non-Seasonal Characters and the paragon experience earned will be transfered over to your non-seasonal pools. (So your Non-Seasonal Hardcore Paragon level will go up but not exactly 30 levels. Just 30 levels worth of experience.)

Non-Seasonal Softcore - Paragon Level 50 - stays the same

- Level 70 Monk
- Level 50 Witch Doctor
- Level 40 Crusader (The same one from Seasonal Above)

Non-Seasonal Hardcore - Paragon Level 10 + 30 levels of experience (level 34ish?)

- Level 70 Barbarian
- Level 70 Monk (The same one from Seasonal Above)

Answer (score 1):

Paragon points are reset each season.   They are bound to each season.

So by you starting a new season character you would start at level 1 and 0 paragon.

If you had leveled a seasonal character to paragon 50 your new character would have them points available.

More info can be found on this link under the paragon 2.0 seasons

http://www.diablowiki.net/Paragon_2.0